# adding parenthesis to a constructor call causes duplicate parameter error in xlc C++ compiler

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor, parentheses, xlc

We are creating a domain specific language that generates C++ code that must compile under gcc and also IBM xlc (version 10.1 for AIX) compilers.

One specific code snippet generated C++ code that works perfectly well under gcc, but no so much under xlc. I have modified the code to the minimum case that still triggers the compile error:

```
//bug183.h
class emptyList
{};

extern emptyList weco;

class otherClass
{
        public:
                otherClass();
                otherClass(const int & p);
                otherClass(const emptyList & e);
                int geta() {return a;}
        private:
                int a;
};

class someClass
{
        public:
                someClass();
                someClass(const someClass & other);
                someClass(const otherClass & p1, const otherClass & p2);
                void exportState();

        private:
                otherClass oc1;
                otherClass oc2;

};

//bug183.cpp
#include "bug183.h"
#include <iostream>

emptyList weco = emptyList();

otherClass::otherClass() {a = 0;}
otherClass::otherClass(const int & p) {a = p;}
otherClass::otherClass(const emptyList & e) {a = 1000;}

someClass::someClass() {oc1 = otherClass(); oc2 = otherClass();}
someClass::someClass(const someClass & other) {oc1 = other.oc1; oc2 = other.oc2;}
someClass::someClass(const otherClass & p1, const otherClass & p2) {oc1 = p1; oc2 = p2;}
void someClass::exportState() {std::cout << oc1.geta() << " " << oc2.geta() << std::endl;}

int main()
{
        someClass dudi;
        dudi.exportState();

        //this line triggers the error in xlc
        someClass nuni = (someClass(otherClass(weco), otherClass(weco)));
        nuni.exportState();

        return 0;
}
```

Compiling this causes the following error to be raised:
"bug183.cpp", line 21.66: 1540-0114 (S) A parameter name must not be the same as another parameter of this function.

but if I remove the enclosing parenthesis on the constructor call like this:

```
someClass nuni = someClass(otherClass(weco), otherClass(weco));
```

The error goes away. Also, if I change `weco` for another extern variable created just as `weco` the error goes away even if I enclose the constructor in parenthesis, so it is safe to say that both conditions need to be present for this error to show up.

Some of you may ask why don't we just remove the parenthesis then, but doing so *may* hurt parts of the code that are working correctly, so I'm inclined towards understanding if this behavior is expected from a C++ compiler or not or if at least there is a known workaround for it.

Comment: Ha, it's misparsing it as a function declaration, because this is almost similar to that syntax (needless to say, xlc is wrong). Try adding parentheses around `otherClass(weco)`, like `(someClass((otherClass(weco)), ...`

Comment: I fail to understand why those parenthesis() must be there. Can you clarify on why/how it may hurt parts of other code? By using these parenthesis, you force the compile to re-evaluate the inner "statement", and probably force the use of a copy constructor as well. I'm sure it's legal C++, but confusing for both human and parser, apparently.

Comment: Or have you tried to throw out the `=` entirely. `someClass nuni(otherClass(weco), otherClass(weco));` The same goes for the declaration of `weco`, btw : `emptyList weco;`

Comment: Pipilio, see [tag:most-vexing-parse]. @WhozCraig, that will _definitely_ hit the most vexing parse. `someClass nuni(otherClass(weco), otherClass(weco))` is a function declaration, and an invalid one.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, adding more parentheses probably will avoid the buggy parse, but instead of adding more clutter just remove the ones that cause the problem in the first place. `A a = A(B(b))` is better than `A a = (A(B(b)))`

Comment: Interestingly, `someClass nuni = someClass(weco, weco);` also works fine in clang, but I'm betting it chokes horridly on xlc (not to mention its dreadful).

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry, it was the first one, and I didn't see that Wakely had already mentioned it.

Comment: @SethCarnegie yeah I knew it was a function decl when i posted it, but I figured if xlc was incorrectly parsing a construct-init as a function, maybe it will parse a function as a construct init =P. Was worth a shot. that compiler seems a little "off".

Comment: @JvO the truth is that removing the enclosing parenthesis is a risky move as we haven't been able to implement decent regression tests. *If* we manage to have them someday we will certainly try to remove them altogether, but for the time being I wanted to find a safe workaround.

Comment: @Pipilio: I don't know what your limitations are for a workaround, but I added one possibility to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that

```
(someClass(otherClass(weco), otherClass(weco)))
```

is being incorrectly parsed as the start of the second production of a *cast-expression*:

> *cast-expression:
>   
>  unary-expression*
>   
>  `(` *type-id* `)` *cast-expression*

Note § 8.2 paragraph 2 (emphasis added):

> The ambiguity arising from the similarity between a function-style cast and a *type-id* can occur in different contexts. The ambiguity appears as a choice between a function-style cast expression and a declaration of a type. The resolution is that **any construct that could possibly be a *type-id* in its syntactic context shall be considered a *type-id***.

If you consider the full syntactic context of the *type-id* in *cast-expression*, it's not possible for `...` in `(..);` to match `type-id`, because the *cast-expression* following the `)` cannot be empty. However, if you only consider the one-token-lookahead context, where the *type-id* must be followed by `)`, it could be plausible that 8.2(2) applies. I'm not really inclined to believe that the intention of the standard was to only consider one-token lookahead, though.

**EDIT**
Reported as gcc bug [50637](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56037). You might want to submit a similar bug report to xlc.

Since gcc 4.7.2 seems to flag the same error as xlc. I played around with gcc a bit, and convinced myself that the problem is that gcc flags the error in the *type-id* (i.e., two parameters with the same name) before it figures out that the parenthesized expression cannot be a *type-id*.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

static const int zero = 0;
int main() {
  // Consistent with 8.2[2]
  // Example 1. Invalid cast.
  // Here, 'int(int(zero))' is a type-id, so the compiler must take
  // the expression to be a cast of '+3' to a function.
  std::cout << (int(int(zero))) + 3 << std::endl;
  // Example 2: No error.
  // The parenthesized expression cannot be a type-id in this context
  std::cout << (int(int(zero))) << std::endl;
  // Example 3: Syntax error: zero redefined.
  // Here the parenthesized expression could be a type-id, so it must
  // be parsed as one, even though the type-id is invalid.
  std::cout << (std::pair<int,int>(int(zero), int(zero))) + 3 << std::endl;

  // Apparently not consistent with 8.2[2]
  // Here the parenthesized expression can't be a type-id, as in example 2.
  // However, the type-id triggers a syntax error, presumably before gcc
  // figures out that it's not a cast-expression.
  std::cout << (std::pair<int,int>(int(zero), int(zero))) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

See it [on lws](http://liveworkspace.org/code/zZ0I9%240). (Toggle between gcc and clang to see the difference.)

Based on the above analysis that the problem is premature triggering of a type-error, here's one possible workaround:

1) Add an alias for weco:

```
emptyList& weco_alias = weco;
```

2) Use one of each:

```
someClass nuni = (someClass(otherClass(weco), otherClass(weco_alias)));
```

This works on both gcc 4.7.2 and clang 3.2 ([lws](http://liveworkspace.org/code/40Swp1%240)).

Comment: Thanks rici, you are absolutely right about later versions of gcc also rising a compilation error for this code. Our project is using gcc 3.4.6, but I tried it out with version 4.5.2 and got an error too. I am not able to determine if any of those compilers is parsing by the rule you posted, though.